# How does one use eigenvalues for model selection?

Tags: pca, survival, modeling

I am familiar with AIC and BIC.  I'm actually comparing model fit of survival data between Cox PH and Aalen additive hazards regression.  As far as I know, with eigenvalues, you have to perform principal components analysis, factor analysis or something similar.  Can this be applied to Cox PH models and Aalen additive hazards models as well?

Comment: Interesting question, but usually spectral analysis on design matrix, i.e., of regression models, would tell about solution stability rather than model complexity.